# redirection command in cron.d

Tags: cron, io-redirection

On a quite busy server, I have a command with redirection:

```
mycommand &> /var/log/mylog
```

which runs properly from the command line, writing the log file.

However, when I include it in cron.d it creates/truncates the log file but doesn't write anything to it.

Is there a reason for it? what could I do in order to have the log file properly written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like that because`&>` is a bash extension, but cron jobs are executed by sh.

Try redirecting both stdout and stderr like this:

`nice -n 9 mycommand > /var/log/mylog 2>&1`

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80632/22467

Comment: Yes, the problem does not depend on nice, but on the shell executed by  crontab: cron commands are executed with sh, and &> isn't implemented in sh, while it is in bash.